# How to call GetGUIThreadInfo() method of WinApi Using JNI to get caret position in Window

Tags: java, winapi, java-native-interface

I am new to JNI and I want to get caret position in windows but while calling GuiThreadInfo() method it requires first to set cbSize of GUITHREADINFO value.
I tried below code  but it doesn't show correct result.
With Example to get caret position will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
HWND hwnd = User32.INSTANCE.GetForegroundWindow();  
IntByReference pId=new IntByReference();  
User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, pId);  
int processId=pId.getValue();  
GUITHREADINFO info=new GUITHREADINFO();  
info.cbSize=info.size();  
User32.INSTANCE.GetGUIThreadInfo(processId, info);  
System.out.println("left :"+info.rcCaret.left+" ,  right :"+info.rcCaret.right);
```

Comment: If you need to know the caret position in another process, chances are, that you should be using [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) instead.

Comment: Thanks IInspectable for your reply,can we call Ui Automation using jni?

Comment: JNI allows you to call any API that provides an interface accessible from C. UI Automation is implemented as a set of COM objects, that are callable from C. Although I don't have any hands-on experience, [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna#readme) could be helpful, since it does provide [COM support](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/tree/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/COM).

Comment: Hi IInspectable ,can you provide solution to get caret position using UI Automation using any java or c++ as example as i tried to get solution but i am not able to find out.