# How to get process id of currently active tab on browser using JNI

Tags: java, c++, winapi, browser, java-native-interface

I tried below code,
but it gives me browser parent thread id.I want to know currently active tab process id using **jni**.
With Example will be really helpful.
Thanks in advance.

```
HWND hwnd = User32.INSTANCE.GetForegroundWindow();
IntByReference pId=new IntByReference();
int tmp= User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, pId);
int processId=pId.getValue();
System.out.println("processId : "+processId);
```

Comment: What does "tab processid" even mean, in general? Browsers are not guaranteed to execute each tab as a separate process. Some may do so, some handle all tabs in one process, some do not even support tabs at all.

Comment: Thanks Hulk for your reply.As Tab process id means i want to get currently active tab processid ,As you said all browser doesn't guaranty to execute each tab as seperate process but like crome browser some browser does that.

Comment: What is the underlying problem?

Comment: I want to get Caret Position in any application using java jni.GetGuiThreadInfo() method working fine,but while getting caret position in browser it returns 0,0 value as caret position because of processid returned is not correct.

Comment: That's not the reason, why you cannot retrieve the caret position. The reason (as hinted in a comment to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34966940/1889329)) is, that the browser doesn't use native controls, and calling APIs that operate on native controls (like `GetGUIThreadInfo`) will not return, what you expect. You have to use UI Automation (see [Caret (MSAA UI Element Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318010.aspx), for example). There are no other options available.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get process ID of tab with Win32 API, because it depends of browser. Not all browsers executes tabs in separate processes.
For Google Chrome you can use it's [API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/processes#method-getProcessIdForTab) for this purpose.